# VBA Access Database - Clean up code by the use of a loop with 2 variables

Tags: arrays, vba, import, ms-access-2010, excel-2010

I'm trying to write a code that imports 4 different files in 4 different databases. I wonder if there is a way to make this much shorter and simpler by using a loop? I tried one, but I can't figure out how to direct one file to a different database.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command5_Click()

Dim StockPath As String
Dim WipsPath As String
Dim CcaPath As String
Dim EpsPath As String


StockPath = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\Stock_getdata.xlsm"
WipsPath = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\Wips_getdata.xlsm"
CcaPath = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\SLAcc.xls"
EpsPath = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\eps.xlsm"

If FileExist(StockPath) Then
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "Stock_CC", StockPath, True
    Else
    MsgBox "Bestanden niet gevonden."
    End If

If FileExist(WipsPath) Then
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "Wips_CC", WipsPath, True
    Else
    MsgBox "Bestanden niet gevonden."
    End If

If FileExist(CcaPath) Then
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "CCA_cc", CcaPath, True
    Else
    MsgBox "Bestanden niet gevonden."
    End If

If FileExist(EpsPath) Then
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "Eps_cc", EpsPath, True
    Else
    MsgBox "Bestanden niet gevonden."
    End If


End Sub


Function FileExist(sTestFile As String) As Boolean
   Dim lSize As Long
   On Error Resume Next
   'Preset length to -1 because files can be zero bytes in length
   lSize = -1
   'Get the length of the file
   lSize = FileLen(sTestFile)
   If lSize > -1 Then
      FileExist = True
   Else
      FileExist = False
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
    Dim fileInfoToBeImported(3, 1)

    fileInfoToBeImported(0, 0) = "Stock_CC"
    fileInfoToBeImported(0, 1) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\Stock_getdata.xlsm"

    fileInfoToBeImported(1, 0) = "Wips_CC"
    fileInfoToBeImported(1, 1) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\Wips_getdata.xlsm"

    fileInfoToBeImported(2, 0) = "CCA_cc"
    fileInfoToBeImported(2, 1) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\SLAcc.xls"

    fileInfoToBeImported(3, 0) = "Eps_cc"
    fileInfoToBeImported(3, 1) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\eps.xlsm"

    Dim loopIndex As Integer
    For loopIndex = 0 To UBound(fileInfoToBeImported, 1)
        transferSpreadsheetMethod fileInfoToBeImported(loopIndex, 0), fileInfoToBeImported(loopIndex, 1)
    Next loopIndex
End Sub

Private Sub transferSpreadsheetMethod(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal fileName As String)
    If FileExist(fileName) Then
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , tableName, fileName, True
    Else
        MsgBox "Bestanden niet gevonden."
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I get an error on the next line:   `If FileExist(StockPath) Then` - StockPath is not defined

Comment: Thanks Nathalii, code now altered - that should have had the actual filename passed in!

Comment: I choose this solution, because i think it's easier to alter in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Im not big on Access but if you put the 4 paths into an array and then loop around the array that should work.

```
Dim Paths(7)
Paths(0) = "Stock_CC"
Paths(1) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\Stock_getdata.xlsm"
Paths(2) = "Wips_CC"
Paths(3) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\Wips_getdata.xlsm"
Paths(4) = "CCA_cc"
Paths(5) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\SLAcc.xls"
Paths(6) = "Eps_cc"
Paths(7) = "F:\370\Hyperviseur\SITUATIE\Macro\eps.xlsm"

for i =0 to ubound(Paths) step 2
    If FileExist(Paths(i+1)) Then
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , Paths(i), Paths(i+1), True
    Else
        MsgBox "Bestanden niet gevonden."
    End If
next
```

You may want to put something in the message box to distinguish between what loop you are in.

Comment: You beat me by seconds posting this! :cP I gave you +1 for your comment on the note for the messagebox - spot on there!

Comment: Cheers, Just to clarify for anyone looking both answers will work just slightly different way of doing it.

Comment: I get an error on the next line:   `If FileExist(StockPath) Then` - StockPath is not defined, And I don't know with what i need to replace it with.

Comment: I have made the change. Good spot.